# Американизмы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Об этом уже писалось тут, но все равно хочу спросить. Когда вообще уместно употреблять англицизмы и прочие "измы"? А то сейчас просто засилие какое-то, и там, где вполне можно употребить русское слово, говорят англицизм. Например, не "уборка", а "клининг", на улицах сплошные, пардон, "шопы". Впрочем, каждый тут может привести миллион примеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если можно сказать уборка, зачем говорить клининг? А вот электронно-вычислительная машина - громоздко, поэтому слово компьютер прижилось. В каждом конкретном случае выбор за Вами. А результат нашего коллективного выбора будет тот язык (речь), который мы получим в результате нашего выбора. Русские слова терять очень жаль! А ведь уходят - вместо "действительный" говорят "реальный", вместо "творческий" - креативный. (Вот даже компьютер эти слова не признает и подчеркивает красным!)

Answer (score 0):

"Измы" вполне пригодны к употреблению, когда нет подходящего существующего русского слова с аналогичным значением.  Именно существующего, а не искусственно образованного или наделённого новым значением. В ином случае измы становятся терминами, а потом и обычными словами.

Конкретно по поводу "креатива" и "клининга". Первое - безусловно "падонкоффское" словечко, ни в каких смыслах кроме ироничного к употреблению не подлежит. А вот с "клинингом" сложнее. Клининг воспринимается не просто как уборка, но как уборка, если так позволено будет выразиться, уборка индустриальная, да ещё и предлагаемая на рынке услуг. К себя дома никто клинингом не занимается. Достаточно ли это для того, чтобы принять слово как нормативное - посмотрим.

Comment: А вот как раз слово "креативный" очень часто употребляется, учителя умудряются даже в характеристику ученика вставить, а администрация замечания сделать о недостатке креатива. (Творчества!!!). Только почему Вы называете его "падонкафским"7 Язык "падонкаф", или "олбанский " язык - это намеренное искажение  правописания слова, а если мы прочитаем такие слова, то вслух ошибки не услышим. Весьма вредное для практической грамотности явление, но интересное.

Comment: Да, я знаю, что "креатив" заполонил просторы не только интернета, но даже телеэфира. Но даже при всем своем достаточно либеральном отношении к подобным явлениям не нахожу оснований для его употребления вне пародийного контекста.

Comment: "Падонкоффский" язык и "олбанский" - это не совсем одно и то же. Я мыслю так, что последнее есть порождение первого, изначально существовавшего вне среды обязательного намеренного искажения орфографии, но допускающего её. Это потом оно, искажение, стало обязательным элементом на сайтах padonki.com и udaff.com  (так, кажется). Сейчас тех сайтов давно нет, а если что и есть, то давно потеряло преемственность с первоисточником.

Comment: Так вот, по моим наблюдениям, именно на удаве и было впервые внедрено это "креатив, креативный" в привычном ныне значении. И написание было правильным (если таковое вообще может быть у подобных слов-сорняков).